# Closed-form to this definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So, I came across this definite integral:
$$\int^1_0 x^n e^{-x} \,\mathrm{d}x$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Is there a closed-form solution (NOT in the form of a series, though) to this integral? I know there is one if the upper limit was infinity, but how about this one?

Thanks!

Comment: @DanielFischer Haha, made the correction!

Comment: I guess $$(-1)^n\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^n\Biggl\lvert_{t=1} \frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}$$ doesn't count as closed form?

Comment: @DanielFischer Nope :3

Comment: Did you try solving it using recurrence, i.e. denote this integral $I_n$ and see if you can express it as a function of $I_{n-1}$

Comment: @Mathguy Yay, I guessed right. Rejoice!!!

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the inputs, but no, I don't know how to solve recurrences (setting up the recurrence relation should be trivial though?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a mere suggestion. Denote the integral in question $I_{n}$ and use integration by parts to obtain
$$
I_n = -e^{-1} + n \int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}e^{-x}dx=-e^{-1} +n I_{n-1}
$$
Can you continue this recurrence? The boundary value exists: $\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x}dx=1-e^{-1}$

Comment: Just read up stuff on recurrences and I guess I can now solve this recurrence using the 'summation' factor method! Nice solution, this.

Answer (score 2):

What gave Alex is more than a suggestion. It is the solution.

However, it exists a closed form solution since the antiderivative of your integrand is
$$-\Gamma (n+1,x)$$ it follows that the integral is $$\Gamma (n+1)-\Gamma (n+1,1)$$

Comment: Oh, the incomplete gamma function? Nice, nice.

Comment: @Mathguy. Glad to know that you like it. However, I really prefer the recurrence relation. Just admit that you have to program it ...

Comment: Not really? It's a simple first order recurrence, and we have $n!$ as its 'summation factor.' So the recurrence can be solved. It's another thing that the resultant sum isn't too 'easy' to represent in a closed-form..